# 'react-bootstrap' does not contain an export named 'Card'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am building a React app with the new react-bootstrap v1 (where Bootstrap 3 for React has changed to no longer include the Panel component - it is now instead replaced with the Card component).  I installed the npm install which is: npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap

But when I go to run the application it tells me: 'react-bootstrap' does not contain an export named 'Card'. Here is what my component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import mealsCall from '../DBRequests/mealCalls';
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


export class Meals extends Component {

    state = {
        meals: [],
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        mealsCall
            .getMeals()
            .then((meals) => {
                this.setState({ meals })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('error with GET meals call', error);
            });
    };

    render() {
        const meals = this.state.meals.map((meal) => {
            return (
                <div key={meal.id}>
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{meal.mealName}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>
                            <h3>{meal.restaurantName}</h3>
                            <h4>{meal.city}, {meal.state}</h4>
                        </Card.Text>
                        <Button variant="primary">View Meal</Button>
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Card>
              </div>
           );
        })
        return (
            <div>
                {meals}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the version of `react-bootstrap` that you have installed?

Comment: Hey @Malias17 which version of React-Bootstrap are you running?

Answer (score 0):

From react-bootstrap version 1.0.0-beta.x:

The correct import statement for Card is

```
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
```

The correct import statement for Button is

```
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
```